# What is the equivalent of NILLABLE from XML to JAVA

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl

what is the equivalent of

```
<Skills/>
<Weapons/>
```

from XML to JAVA?
Im working on SOAP so I had to ask.

Also there are elements like

```
<Skills nillable = true>
```

Are these required in objects in Java? Or can I just assign null values to them?

Answer (score 1):

In Java there is nothing like `nillable = true`. But you can assign a `null` value to an object reference:

```
Skills mySkills = null;
Weapons myWeapons = null;
```